# Java different parameter type needed for identical SOAP Web Service?

Tags: java, soap, jax-ws

I have a Web Service client for 2 identical SOAP Web Services called Company1Service and Company2Service. Both these web services have the exact same PurchaseOrder class.

However, when I want to call the m1ProcessPurchaseOrder() method and the m2ProcessPurchaseOrder() method from each web service, they require different parameter types for the Po object. Yet, the PurchaseOrder class is identical for both services.

I am using NetBeans and the Generated Sources (jax-ws).

```
public boolean m1ProcessPurchaseOrder(ab.service.company1.PurchaseOrder Po) 
{
    ab.service.company1.Company1Service port = service1.getComapny1ServicePort();
    return port.processPurchaseOrder(po);
}

public boolean m2ProcessPurchaseOrder(ab.service.company2.PurchaseOrder Po) 
{
    ab.service.company2.Company2Service port = service2.getComapny2ServicePort();
    return port.processPurchaseOrder(po);
}
```

What I would like to do is have `ab.service.company1.PurchaseOrder` be the parameter type for both the Company1Service and the Company2Service.

Here is my error if I try to change `m2ProcessPurchaseOrder()` parameter type to `ab.service.company1.PurchaseOrder`:

> method processPurchaseOrder in interface Company2Service cannot be applied to given types;
>
> Required: ab.service.Company2.PurchaseOrder
>
> Found: ab.service.Company1.PurchaseOrder
>
> Reason: actual argument ab.service.Company1.PurchaseOrder cannot be converted to ab.service.Company2.PurchaseOrder by method invocation conversion

Comment: It's hard to know how `PurchaseOrder` class/type is constructed. Is it being generated from an XSD Schema type? Obviously, two services, `Company1Service` and `Company2Service`, use two different classes, `*.company1.PurchaseOrder` and `*.company2.PurchaseOrder` (note the package names are different, and therefore, the two `PurchaseOrder`'s are considered to be two different types). Are you by any chance using JAXB to generate `PurchaseOrder`'s? If so, you can use binding documents to generate `PurchaseOrder` into a same package and use it in both services.

Comment: Yes, I am using JAXB. How can I use the binding documents for this?

Comment: Depends on the data contract between your client and the webservice. The namespaces for both types are part of the contract i.e. company 2 won't accept a `PurchaseOrder` from the namespace of  `ab.service.company1`

Comment: Do you know of any tutorial or resources that would show me how have PurchaseOrder be shared among ab.service.company1 and ab.service.company2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what *JAX-WS* implementation you are using -- there are severals: *CXF*, *RI/Metro*, *Axis2*, *JBossWS*, *Spring-WS*, etc. -- you might be needing to invoke different tools to generate your artifacts (*XSD* Schemas or *WSDL*'s), i.e. RI's ***wsimport***, or a specific JAX-WS implementation tools like *Axis*2's or *CXF*'s ***WSDL2Java***, or *JBossWS*' ***wsprovide***.

Also, depending on what build script/tool you have setup for your project, there might be a task, goal, or a target that you can utilize to automate the invocation of these tools. Nevertheless, when it comes to XML-to-Java binding, you can utilize *JAXB* Binding document(s) to manipulate the generated Java classes including the manipulation of where (package) they are generated into. This is done via ***jaxb:bindings*** (*jaxb* is just a namespace prefix). For *WSDL* artifacts, i.e. service, you can place your mapping instructions in ***jaxws:bindings*** (same here *jaxws* is just an XML namespace). Note that these two are two separate binding (*XML*) documents which can be fed to one of the aforementioned tools, i.e. *CXF*'s *WSDL2Java* or *wsimport*.

For a *JAXB* binding, you can create a binding document like (`Company1Binding.xml`):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1">

  <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="PurchaseOrder.xsd">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
      <jaxb:package name="ab.service.common" />
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
  </jaxb:bindings>

  <!-- more binding related to Company1Service -->

</jaxb:bindings>
```

and a JAXB binding for `Company2Binding.xml`:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.1">

  <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="PurchaseOrder.xsd">
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
      <jaxb:package name="ab.service.common" />
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
  </jaxb:bindings>

  <!-- more binding related to Company2Service -->

</jaxb:bindings>
```

This would place a generated `PurchaseOrder.java` class in `ab.service.common` package, so you can reference the instances of this class in `ab.service.company1.*` and `ab.service.company2.*` from this single class (`ab.service.common.PurchaseOrder.java`).

Note that I place such binding in both Company1's and Company2's in case you make changes to PurchaseOrder.xsd at some point, and generate the binding only one of the services, i.e. Company1's. In this case, PurchaseOrder.java is regenerated for both, since there is only one generated class for it (`ab.service.common.PurchaseOrder.java`).

You can do the same with *WSDL* artifacts, for example for `Comapny1Service.wsdl`, you can create a new binding document like (`Company1ServiceBinding.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxws:bindings xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    version="2.1" xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
    wsdlLocation="Company1Service.wsdl">

    <jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions">
        <jaxws:package
            name="ab.service.company1" />
    </jaxws:bindings>

    <jaxws:bindings
        node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:portType/wsdl:operation/wsdl:fault[@name='fault']">
        <jaxws:class
            name="ab.service.common.ServiceException" />
    </jaxws:bindings>

</jaxws:bindings>
```

Which would place the service classes (like the interface, client proxy, along side, say, Soap Fault type you specified in your WSDL for the operations) in `ab.service.Company1` package. Notice the difference between the namespaces in each binding document (`jaxb:bindings` vs. `jaxws:bindings`). Finally, you can pass these binding information to the actual tool, i.e. *CXF*'s *WSDL2Java* (in this case, a snippet of code from *Ant* build file):

```
<java classname="org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava" fork="true">
    <arg value="-d"/>
    <arg value="${path.to.generated.code}"/>
    <arg value="-b"/>
    <arg value="${path.to.artifacts}/Company1Binding.xml"/>
    <arg value="-b"/>
    <arg value="${path.to.artifacts}/Company1ServiceBinding.xml"/>
    <arg value="${path.to.artifacts}/Company1Service.wsdl"/>
    <classpath>
        <path refid="${jaxws.impl.library.path}"/>
    </classpath>
</java>
```

(NOTE: you should have a similar target for *Company2Service*)

As you can see, this particular tool accepts binding documents (*JAXB* and *JAX-WS*) via a `-b` flag. As a matter of fact, the [Binding Compiler (xjc)](https://jaxb.java.net/2.2.4/docs/xjc.html) which these tools, like *WSDL2Java*, ultimately call, do accept the binding documents via `-b` option (note the link takes you to *Reference Implementation/Metor*'s version of *xjc*, but *CXF*'s and others' should be close). As a matter of fact, you could have just call the *WSDL2Java* itself directly:

```
/path/to/wsdltojava -d /path/to/where/you/want/to/generate -b /path/to/wsdl/artifacts/CompanyBinding.xml -b /path/to/wsdl/artifacts/Company1ServiceBinding.xml /path/to/wsdl/artifacts/Company1Service.wsdl
```

Mapping using *JAXB* requires getting yourself familiarized with a bit of details, but you can [read more about it here](https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/) which is *JAX-WS RI/Metro*'s. For *CXF*'s, you can [refer to here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html), and some examples for [Maven's plugin](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html) for *CXF*'s *WSDL2Java*. Again, every *JAX-WS* implementation has its own set of tools, but the concepts are identical when it comes to the underlying mapping/binding which is tied to *JAXB*.

Comment: Thanks alot for the very detailed information. I'll give it a try. I just noticed that NetBeans has an option for creating a JAXB binding XML file in a project. Is this related to the steps you mentioned above?

Comment: JAXB plugins for every IDE is different (I've used Eclipse's, and to be exact [IBM] RAD's edition but use build scripts, like Ant, to generate multiple of these mappings as the plugin is for manual generation), and each plugin + IDE might be using a different underlying tool (WSDL2JAVA, wsimport, etc.). Regardless, NetBeans' wizard plugin seems like it allows you to use JAXB binding configuration ([take a look at this page](https://netbeans.org/kb/74/websvc/jaxb.html)).